# Can a google add-on copy files from my Drive to a user's folder? Is there any way to do this?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
Var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file) //in my Drive
DriveApp.getRootFolder.addFile(file); //in user' s Drive
```

Comment: If your file in your Drive is shared to everyone, it would work as long as the user who installs the Add-on gives permission for the Add-on to access their Drive.  If you do not want to share your file to everyone, there is a way that you could grant either edit or view permission to the installer.  If you are interested, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy from files on your Google Drive to a folder on other user's Drive.

1. `addFile()` you use is used for adding parents to a file. `addFile()` cannot be used for other user's folder even if the folder was shared. If you want to use the file together with the user, please share a file with the user.
2. If you want to use the file separately with the user, you can use `makeCopy()`. When you want to copy files to the user's folder, **please share with you the destination folder which is the folder on user's Drive**.

The sample script is as follows.

**Sample Script :**

```
var srcfileid = "### file id ###"; // This file is your file.
var destfolderid = "### folder id ###"; // This folder is user's folder.

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(srcfileid)
file.makeCopy(file.getName(), DriveApp.getFolderById(destfolderid));
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script add-ons run as the user who installed them. Moving the file from your Drive to someone else's account would require the script to somehow gain access to your account. I don't think Google will ever allow this to happen. However, I'm not sure if your question was really about the add-ons as described here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/

Comment: If the file in the Add-on creators account is shared to the public, then it's possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone. I'll try it.